# Replace NaN values of filtered column by the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following shape:

```
Index([u'PRODUCT',u'RANK', u'PRICE', u'STARS', u'SNAPDATE', u'CAT_NAME'], dtype='object')
```

For each product of that dataframe I can have NaN values for a specific date.

The goal is to replace for each product the NaN values by the mean of the existing values.

Here is what I tried without success:

```
for product in df['PRODUCT'].unique():
        df = df[df['PRODUCT'] == product]['RANK'].fillna((df[df['PRODUCT'] == product]['RANK'].mean()), inplace=True)

print df
```

gives me:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to create a mean series:

```
s = df.groupby('PRODUCT')['RANK'].mean()
```

Then use this series to `fillna` values:

```
df['RANK'] = df['RANK'].fillna(df['PRODUCT'].map(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because of your use of [`inplace` in `fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html). Unfortunately, the documentation there is wrong:

> Returns:  filled : Series

This shows otherwise, though:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3]})

>>> type(df.a.fillna(6, inplace=True))
NoneType

>>> type(df.a.fillna(6))
pandas.core.series.Series
```

So when you assign

```
df = df[df['PRODUCT'] == product]['RANK'].fillna((df[df['PRODUCT'] == product]['RANK'].mean()), inplace=True)
```

you're assigning `df = None`, and the next iteration fails with the error you get.

You can omit the assignment `df =`, or, better yet, use the other answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, so using my code without the inplace=True would work?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO Probably yes, although it's possible you're missing a `.loc` in the middle (you didn't provide sample data, so it's hard to check it). In any case, you should use the other answer - loops should be avoided when using Pandas.

Comment: Thank you very much